# Jquery fadeout speed won't apply

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a problem with the jquery fadeout. I tried to set 3000 Milliseconds but it won't apply

I use:

```
$('#alertSuccess').fadeOut('3000', function() {
    document.getElementById("alertSuccess").style.display = "none";
});
```

but it still disappears very very fast ( i guess the default 400milli seconds)..

Anyone know why?

Comment: Try it without the quotes around 3000

Comment: you can change this `document.getElementById("alertSuccess").style.display = "none";` to `$(this).hide();`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.fadeOut(3000, function() { ... }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this code:

```
html:
<div id="box1" class="box">linear</div>
```

Then use this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

function complete() {
document.getElementById("alertSuccess").style.display = "none";
}

 $("#box1").fadeOut(3000,complete);

});
```

you can check this code on http://jsfiddle.net/FLARH/